# Eclipse for Java shows Multiple Errors

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, version

This is my current configuration:

> Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
>
> Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
>
> Java Version 8 Update 45 Build 1.8.0_45-b15

After a time *without using* some Java Project folders, now Eclipse throws a lot of syntaxis errors over them:

```
The import javafx cannot be resolved
*** cannot be resolved to a type
The method join(String, List<String>) is undefined for the type String
```

The project folder never change from their location, they were error and warning free prior to left them *abandoned*.

I am not sure about a missing `.metadata` or `.reccomenders` or a Java version change -over no more than two months- for these projects.

What should i do to solve that?

Comment: Do you have the right JRE/JDK selected in Eclipse's settings?

Comment: I tried but it worked for only one project... the Project>Clean approach was the final solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cleaning your project by going to the following menu item:

```
Project > Clean...
```

If that doesn't work:

- Try removing the jars from the build path and adding them again.
- Double-check the jars being really on the build path (with no errors).
- Make sure there is nothing in the "Problems" view.